# How to close access application if a user doesn't do anything for a while?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm going to copy a DB every certain period of time e.g. every half an hour (reserve copy). My compressed DB isn't so big, it's about 5 Mb. Are there any ways to close access application if a user doesn't do anything for a while? Please answer in general, at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow this guide:

[ACC: How to Detect User Idle Time or Inactivity](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/128814)

It goes through how to set it up and how to add `Application.Quit` function to the VBAscript

To determine the inactivity time before the application quits, change `IDLEMINUTES = 5` to `IDLEMINUTES = 30` for 30 minutes for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Quit` after a certain amount of time has past. Measure the amount using the `Timer` function [Look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/gg264416.aspx)